# Can hide ProgressBar but cannot show it

Tags: java, android, android-progressbar

I'm using the default ProgressBar widget, for indeterminate progress, in a Linear Layout with Style: `@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Small`

If I start the activity with the ProgressBar VISIBLE and never make it INVISIBLE or GONE it shows ok. But if I put `progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.GONE);` or `progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.INVISIBLE);` anywhere in my code, the space for the ProgressBar is on the UI, but I cant see it.

I thought it might be a leaky parallel thread and removed all multi-threading from my app, but it still won't appear if **INVISIBLE** or **GONE** is anywhere in my code.

It works fine on other Activities.

Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="260dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myTeamsScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="32dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="32dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/menu1ImageView"
                        android:layout_width="30dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/userNavigationMenuButtonContent"
                        android:onClick="openDrawer"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_icon" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/enterNewTeamEditText"
                android:layout_width="340dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:contentDescription="@string/enterTeamNameEditTextcontent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/teamNameHint"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/myTeamsProgressBar"
                style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Small"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:foregroundTint="#FFFFCC"
                android:progressTint="#FFFFCC"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/deckTypeTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/remotePokerlabelcontent"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="@string/newTeamDeckType"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/remotePokerTextView" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/newTeamDeckTypeSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/enterNewTeamEditText" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/createTeamButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/colorButton"
                android:contentDescription="@string/createTeamButtoncontent"
                android:fontFamily="@string/fontfamily"
                android:onClick="createTeam"
                android:text="Create Team"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/receivedJoinRequestsButton"
                android:layout_width="147dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@color/colorButton"
                android:contentDescription="@string/createTeamButtoncontent"
                android:fontFamily="@string/fontfamily"
                android:onClick="showJoinRequests"
                android:text="@string/myTeamsJoinRequestsButton"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/teamTypesSwitch"
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:checked="false"
                android:fontFamily="@string/fontfamily"
                android:text="@string/switchMemberTeams"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/myTeamsListView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:alwaysDrawnWithCache="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/myTeamsListViewcontent"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true"
                    android:scrollbars="vertical"
                    android:scrollingCache="true"
                    android:smoothScrollbar="true"></ListView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:onClick="onSwitchChange"
        app:headerLayout= "@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@xml/drawer_view" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

In the Activity onCreate I call `populateMemberTeams();` I added a CountDownTimer to check if the progressBar is on the screen and it is...**Before the 2 seconds, there is a empty space, but I can't see the ProgressBar**

**When the timer expires the UI adjusts when the ProgressBar changes to GONE.**

```
private void populateMemberTeams() {
    ListView myTeamsListView = findViewById(R.id.myTeamsListView);
    ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.myTeamsProgressBar);

    progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.VISIBLE);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    callTeamManagement.populateMemberTeams(TAG, passedActivity, context, userId);

    new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
        public void onFinish() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.GONE);
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // millisUntilFinished    The amount of time until finished.
        }

    }.start();

}
```

I have tried:

- Changing the ProgressBar **style** in case it was a colour issue;
- **INVISIBLE** instead of **GONE**;
- Putting the ProgressBar inside its own LinearLayout
- `progressBar.setVisibility(progressBar.VISIBLE);`
- `progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
- `progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**`runOnUiThread`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/rule/UiThreadTestRule).

> Helper method for running part of a method on the UI thread.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
       progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
       //progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment but that is not working. I cannot see the progressBar even though I can see the UI adjusting when it disappears with GONE. @IntelliJ Amiya